# Do feats and abilities that improve a spell work on supernatural abilities?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, domains

I was considering taking the Envy domain because I happen to have the supernatural ability to drain ability scores like a succubus. Would the Envy domain's granted power apply to this supernatural ability? What about Spell Focus (enchantment) applying to some of the enchantment-school supernatural abilities?

Comment: "I happen to have the supernatural ability to ability scores" - I don't know if I'm missing something but this doesn't make sense to me. Are you missing a word?

Comment: @doppelgreener he happened to have supernatural ability to drain ability scores. then he edited during grace period (hence no edit history) and somehow removed important part of the sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Typically, effects that specify they affect *only* spells don't also affect supernatural abilities

Feats like [Spell Focus](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/featsAll.html#spell-focus) (*Player's Handbook* 100), metamagic feats like [Quicken Spell](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/featsAll.html#quicken-spell) (*PH* 98), and domain granted powers that say they affect spells (like the granted powers of the domains Creation (*Spell Compendium* 272) and Envy (*SpC* 273-7)) typically affect *only* spells, *not* [special abilities](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/abilitiesAndConditions.html#special-abilities) like extraordinary abilities, spell-like abilities, or supernatural abilities.

For example, a [succubus](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/monstersDtoDe.html#succubus-demon) (*Monster Manual* 47-8) that wants to improve its supernatural ability energy drain could take the feat [Ability Focus](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/monsterFeats.html#ability-focus) (energy drain) (*MM* 303), but its supernatural ability energy drain wouldn't be improved if the succubus were to take the feat Spell Focus (necromancy). Similarly, an umber hulk's supernatural ability confusion gaze (*MM* 249) (which creates an effect like the spell [*confusion*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsC.html#confusion) (*PH* 212), a spell of the enchantment school) isn't improved by the feat Spell Focus (enchantment).